# Как исправить грязный JSON файл полученный при парсинге

Tags: python, json

При парсинге получаю "грязный" Json файл, в котором в начале и в конце имеются элементы, которые не являются форматом Json.

Код программы

```
import json
import cloudscraper
from parsel import Selector

url = "https://opensea.io/rankings"

def Info():

    scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
    osinfo = scraper.get(url)

    sel = Selector(text=osinfo.text)
    data = sel.xpath('//*[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]').get()
    
    with open('data.txt','w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(data)
        
    data = json.load()
    print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Info()
```

Грязный Json файл

```
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"isDesktop":true, ...} </script>
```

Т.е мешается script, который парсится со странички. Как его можно убрать?

Comment: Подозреваю что в xpath можно просто дописать `/text()`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, разобрался. Помогло

Answer (score 4):

Помогло добавление в конец xpath "/text()".

Вот так выглядит исправленный вариант:

```
data = sel.xpath('//*[@id="__NEXT_DATA__"]/text()').get()
```

Comment: Предлагаю Вам отметить этот ответ как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста :)

Comment: @4500zenja, так только через 2 дня можно собственный ответ принимать.